# Permission denied on adb pull junit-report.xml created by android-junit-report

Tags: android, junit, adb

I'm using [android-junit-report](http://zutubi.com/source/projects/android-junit-report/documentation/) to be able to publish Junit test result report in my Jenkins machine. I followed that documentation and it says:

*Note: by default only the application under test has full access to the directory where the report is stored. You will not be able, for example, to list the contents of the directory unless you have a rooted device. The runner marks the file as world-readable, though, so knowing the full path you are able to pull it from the device.*

When I try to **adb pull** I get **permission denied**. Someone faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should set reportDir to a location in the external storage:

> reportDir
>
> If specified, absolute path to a directory in which to write the
>   report file(s). May begin with **external**, which will be replaced
>   with the path for the external storage area of the application under
>   test. This requires external storage to be available and
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the application under test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Milano but this is mandatory? I thought I would be able to just pull without doing this. If I do that using ant it is still necessary?

Answer (score 0):

junit-report generation has nothing to do with permission issue as long as create it anywhere under /data/data/package_name/

Can you see the file in ddms? if you do you do not have any problem with Junit-report. leave junit-report side. But if you don't you can try some other instrumentation like [this](http://zutubi.com/source/projects/android-junit-report/) one.

Now if you see the file, then resolve issue with adb?

- is this about this specific device? try it on different one.
- wrong path?

Comment: I'm using exactly the one that you linked. And yes, the file is being created but I can't access it by adb pull because it shows permission denied even with the documentation saying the file is world-readable.

Comment: it is nothing to do with file. I have implemented jenkins with similar feature, and its working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve with the **ant** solution given in the [enter link description here](http://zutubi.com/source/projects/android-junit-report/documentation/). I don't know if the file is world-readable but **adb pull** on my device returned permission denied. Perhaps it depends on the device type.

I added in my build.xml:

```
<target name="fetch-test-report" >
    <xpath
        expression="/manifest/@package"
        input="${tested.project.dir}/AndroidManifest.xml"
        output="tested.package" />
    <echo>Downloading XML test report...</echo>
    <exec
        executable="${adb}"
        failonerror="true" >
        <arg line="${adb.device.arg}" />
        <arg value="pull" />
        <arg value="/data/data/${tested.package}/files/junit-report.xml" />
        <arg value="report/junit-report.xml" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

copy to sdcard/datas/ then pull again. Hope fun